# discord js I need to fetch and delete messages more than discord limit (100) allows

Tags: discord.js, bots, message

```
let purgingCounter = splitMsg[1];
          function purging() {
            client.channels.cache.get(channelTarget).messages.fetch({ limit: [1]})
            .then(data => {
              let messageArr = [...data];
              console.log(messageArr[0][1]);
              console.log(`Second log ${messageArr[0][1].id}`);
              client.channels.cache.get(channelTarget).messages.delete(messageArr[0][1].id);
              console.log(`purged`);
              purgingCounter-=1;
            })
            .then(() => {
              if (purgingCounter>0) {
                purging();
              }
            });
          };
          purging();
```

Once deleted I want to check if user wanted to delete more than set limit and repeat the function (because discord has a limit of 100), but it gets called twice and ends up crashing after deleting one message.

Comment: Your goal is to find out why your code gets executed twice, not fetching or deleting

Answer (score 0):

```
async function purging (counter) {
            let data = await client.channels.cache.get(channelTarget).messages.fetch({ limit: [100]})
            let messageArr = [...data];
            for (let i=0; i<messageArr.length; i++) {
              console.log(`Ids purging: ${messageArr[i][1].id}`);
              await client.channels.cache.get(channelTarget).messages.delete(messageArr[i][1].id);
              counter-=1;
              if (counter<=0) {
                return;
              }
            };
            //Check if user wanted to delete more than limit, Timeout makes sure it's the last bit of code to execute
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(`calling back ${counter}`);
              if (counter>0) {
                purging(counter);
              } else { return };
            }, 1);
          }
          purging(splitMsg[1]);
```

basically this is what I wanted, it works, it deletes messages over limit and doesn't delete more than asked.